# Change background before creating adapter

Tags: android

I am creating an arrayadapter with this line:

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.message_bar,strArr);
```

And this is my message_bar.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="dfgdfgdf"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mes4" />
```

Can I change this xml's background and gravity before creating adapter with java ?

Comment: can you call `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.message_bar,strArr);` after onCreate()?

Comment: Yes.  Did you try it?

Comment: No,I can't call after onCreate()

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense. The best thing to do is to create a custom adapter.

Comment: ok,I will create a custom adapter.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom adapter.

```
class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        LayoutInflater inflater=null;

        public Myadapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
             inflater = (LayoutInflater)getLayoutInflater();
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View row = convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

             // CHANGE COLOR HERE
             ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setBackground( Color.Red );

            return row;
        }
    }
```

or override getview:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.message_bar,strArr)
    {
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            View row = convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row =vi.inflate(R.layout.message_bar, null);
            }

            TextView txt= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.message);

            //CHANGE COLOR HERE

            return row;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is there another way to do withoud custom adapter ?

Comment: I am getting this error:The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) in the type ArrayAdapter<String> is not applicable for the arguments (AdapterView, View, int, long)

Comment: Correct arguments are: (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Comment: getApplicationContext works instead of Context variable ? Because I am using this code in fragment.

Comment: you can use getActivity() in a fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62269/discussion-between-serkay-sariman-and-jms).